# Copy data from one sql server to another over LAN programatically

Tags: c#, sql

I have one SQL server A located at some place which contains huge number of records(raw data). A continuosuly running process (C# .NET) from there will notify me if there are records that needs to be processed via web service (WCF) and I need to move that record to my SQL server B for processing. What is the elegant and efficient way to do that?

I have a couple of thoughts on that:
1) Sent the records in batches from one to the other via WCF.
2) Save the records in a file and load it to FTP. Then I can download it from there and upload the records to my DB.

Is there any other better way to do that?

Comment: Are these servers on two different networks?

Comment: Are all of the built in methods for SQL server unacceptable? Log shipping and mirroring can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a couple of thoughts on that: 1) Sent the records in batches from one to the other via WCF. 2) Save the records in a file and load it to FTP. Then I can download it from there and upload the records to my DB.

This really depends on how real-time the data needs to be. In our organization we use a lot of MQ's to keep data synchronized because it needs to be updated real-time between differing applications.

## REAL-TIME

If the data needs to be real-time, and you can setup an MQ, that's what I'd recommend. They are fast, light-weight, and durable. They do take some work to setup, but [here is a link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb684791.aspx) that can get you started.

## BATCH

If the data can be updated in batch you're going to be better off. Real-time data, and the issues that come along with triage, is a lot more complex and cumbersome in practice. With a batch file you can validate and sanitize the data up front to ensure the `CRUD` operations will succeed. With batch, use a text file, delimited or fixed, and import it using an SSIS job. SSIS can pull it down from the FTP Server **and** import it, all in one fell swoop.

Comment: Its not a real time update. So I hope ftp option would be good. Thanks for responding.